# how to access own Node.js server in https web site which deployed in nginx

Tags: node.js, express, https

i do deploy a website in nginx and translate it from http to https using `let's cerbot` before. it runs well.
My question is, in my website, i need to access my own `Node.js Server` using `axios`. As before, i used `http`, it goes well expect security.But now, below the Https connect, the browser blocks my http connect.So i tried update my Node Server to support Https connect using `Self-signed SSL certificates`, but the browser blocks it as well.
Who can tell me how can i fix this problem and make the site work well.Thank you!

Comment: Did you tried to setup nginx as reverse proxy for nodejs server?

Comment: i did not. i will try it. it may be the right direction.

Comment: yep, i fixed the problem as you said, thx!

Comment: I tracked the comment as answer to your question. Please vote the answer.

Comment: no problem, thanks you

Comment: no problem, thanks you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should setup nginx as reverse proxy for nodejs server